# Jquery onclick function called two time on dynamically added button element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have created a code on my HTML page that their multiple checkboxes and created one button dynamically in js snippet for performing some event, but when I clicked on the button to perform that even that, then it's making calls to that event snippet two times. I wanted to know how to add the event to that button.

Here is the js code:-

```
$(".panel-body").on("click", '#select_none', function(event) {
     $("input[name='nodelevel']:checkbox").each(function() {
         this.checked = false;
     });
});
```

Comment: Does `#select_none` has two `.panel-body` parent?

Comment: If you're working with checkbox, you might want to use the "change" event rather than "click". Also, in any case, please share the HTML and/or CSS required to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I changed the  `.panel-body` to `document` and it's working. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure there is only one parent with `.panel-body` class name. maybe there is two of `.panel-body` and it makes this happen. like this:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  ...
  <div class="panel-body">
    ...
      <!-- your selectors -->
  </div>
</div>
```

try `stoppropagation` to avoid second parent event listener call:

```
$(".panel-body").on("click", '#select_none', function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     $("input[name='nodelevel']:checkbox").each(function() {
         this.checked = false;
     });
});
```

EDIT : and of course you can add listener to `document` instead of `.panel-body` :)

Comment: Got you there was more than one parent with `.panel-body` class name.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
<input class="itemClass" type="checkbox" name="Items" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input class="itemClass" type="checkbox" name="Items" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
<button name="submit" onclick="getValue()" value="Submit">
```

Then:

```
    function getValue() {
                var id;
                var name;
                var temp = [];

                $('.itemClass').each(function () {
                    var sThisVal = (this.checked ? $(this).val() : "");
                    console.log(sThisVal);

                    if (this.checked) {
                        // $("input[name=Items]:checked").map(function () {
                        temp.push(sThisVal);
                    }
                });
                console.log(temp);
                $('.itemCheckboxClass').prop('checked', false);
            }
```